# Moving Folder redirection to new drive

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, network-attached-storage, folder-redirection

I need some help with folder redirection we are using server 2012 r2 for DC1 and File server with folder redirection for following folders (app data, desktop, documents and favorites), the problem is folder redirection is going into K drive and we are running out of disk space in K drive so i have attached Synology NAS as iSCSI target to increase disk space in file server for our K drive, now i want to move folder redirection to new K drive because i couldn't extend the existing k drive space, synology iscsi disk space is just showing up as separate 11 TB of disk space in file server disk management, so should i turn of folder redirection and configure new K drive with large disk space or if is there any way if i can just extend the existing K drive space using our NAS iscsi target please advise and if i disable folder redirection GPO would it cause any problem to users.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mount point in your K: that point to that volume, but I don't suggest it as it can get real complex to debug if a technician get to debug that.

I seen a case in the past, as the technician think it was safe to remove a standalone disk because a RAID-5 in the server was in a ok state, and when he unplugged the drive all the user data were lost.

In your folder redirection you surely point to a share, not the K: volume directly, thus I would copy the file in a maintenance windows, and I would move the share to the other volume after.

Comment: Perfect sounds like a plan, but i didn't  understand copy the file in maintenance window part

Comment: @user313162 You copy the file from the K: to the other volume, and you do that when the minimum number of user are online, thus the maintenance windows come into play. As like when you reboot the server in example, you do that after

Comment: I have added more disk space using iscsi nas target now i have changed the drive letter K to P and assigned K to our new driver with larger space but the problem is drive mapping gpo is pushing new K drive but not showing all the folders in it.

Comment: @user313162 You didn't needed to change the driver letter, just the share, can you show the share vs the GPO what is set there ? as I think your share don't point the good location

Comment: Its correctly mapped using FQDN exactly the way it was before but i think i should have remove the old K drive using GPO with the option of Delete and the force it to network does this make sense to you ?

Comment: share does point correctly to a drive letter this company is been sharing entire drive for years so i cant't change because there are many services using the these shared drives